# usage for uvm_re_match function

Tags: uvm

I am having following code for `uvm_re_match`:

```
int temp_int = 20;
temp_int = uvm_re_match(uvm_glob_to_re("abc"), "top.mydut_abc_comp_inst");
$display("\t uvm_re_match USAGE: The result - temp_int = %0d \n",temp_int);
```

I am getting `temp_int = 1`, indicating `"abc"` not found in the string provided.

Any suggestions on `uvm_re_match` and `uvm_glob_to_re` usage.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you have to make sure that you are using UVM together with its DPI code, i.e. the `UVM_NO_DPI` **isn't** defined. It's easy to check this by printing the result of `uvm_glob_to_re("abc")`. If the result is still `"abc"`, then you're using the SystemVerilog version of the function (which just returns the argument) and not the DPI-C implementation. See `dpi/uvm_regex.svh` for the code.

Assuming you're using the DPI functions, you're making a mistake with your glob expression. A glob expression of `"abc"` isn't supposed to match your string. You need to use `"*abc*"` (glob) to match it. You can see that this wouldn't work by looking at the regex versions of the two expressions:

```
module top;
  import uvm_pkg::*;

  initial begin
    static string re1 = uvm_glob_to_re("abc");
    static string re2 = uvm_glob_to_re("*abc*");
    $display(re1);
    $display(re2);
  end
endmodule
```

You'll see that `re1` contains `"/^abc$/"` which can only ever match `"abc"`. `re2` contains `/^.*abc.*$/`, which matches any `"abc"` sub-string in a string. You can just ignore the `/` characters at the beginning and the end as these will get stripped away (not sure why they're there).

If you try to match the two expressions you'll see that the first one doesn't match, whereas the second one does:

```
if (!uvm_re_match(re1, "top.mydut_abc_comp_inst"))
  $display("matches re1");

if (!uvm_re_match(re2, "top.mydut_abc_comp_inst"))
  $display("matches re2");
```

Bonus: another regular expression that would match your string is `"abc"`, which you can see also works with `uvm_re_match(...)`:

```
if (!uvm_re_match("abc", "top.mydut_abc_comp_inst"))
  $display("matches re3");
```

Comment: The bonus expression is not working:

    if (!uvm_re_match("abc", "top.mydut_abc_comp_inst"))
       $display("matches re3");

Comment: @dvguy I've tried it in 3 different simulators and it works. Are you compiling the DPI code yourself or using the UVM that comes with the simulator?

Comment: @dvguy After looking at this a big more, 'abc' shouldn't match 'top.mydut_abc_comp_inst'. A re.search('abc', ...) should be successful, because it tries to find the pattern in the text, but not a match should fail.